# bitmap format for CMYK

Tags: color, cmyk, file-format, bitmap, rasterization

I would like to perform automated rasterization effects on my graphic, then send the result to a printer. ImageMagick supports the effects I require, and supports CMYK. However, I would need to be able to express the input and receive the output as CMYK bitmaps, and bitmap formats appear generally to limit color support to RGB.

Are any bitmap formats available that I might use in this project?

Comment: "*send the result to a printer*" -- what printer? A commercial printer, an end-use home inkjet? A laser printer? Why do you feel you *must* have CMYK? Any end use inkjet printer will work best with RGB data, not CMYK.

Answer (score 3):

[TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) is probably your next best option of a raster format that does support CMYK.